# Add headers and native library to Android project

Tags: android, cmake, ninja

I got some C code I have to integrate into my Android project. It depends on a library (.so), and I also have the .h files.

I copied the libs and include directories into the project's cpp package to make them easier to find.

To make it easier I tried starting with the HelloJNI project Android Studio offers and followed the instructions [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/configure-cmake#add-other-library).

This is the CMakeLists.txt:

```
#given from HelloJNI
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

add_library(hello-jni SHARED
            hello-jni.c)

# Include libraries needed for hello-jni lib
target_link_libraries(hello-jni
                      android
                      log)
#my own additions now:
add_library( # Specifies the name of the library.
        libgdndk

        # Sets the library as a shared library.
        SHARED

        # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
        IMPORTED)
set_target_properties( # Specifies the target library.
        libgdndk

        # Specifies the parameter you want to define.
        PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION

        # Provides the path to the library you want to import.
        ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/libs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libgdndk.so )
include_directories(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/inc/)
target_link_libraries( hello-jni libgdndk app-glue ${libgdndk} )
```

This results in an error:

```
ninja: error: 'libs/armeabi-v7a/libgdndk.so', needed by 'C:/workspace/android/HelloJNI/app/build/intermediates/cmake/arm7/debug/obj/armeabi-v7a/libhello-jni.so', missing and no known rule to make it
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be linking your imported library to the `hello-jni` target *twice*. Also, using `${}` in the `target_link_libraries()` command for the `libgdndk` library is not necessary. You have already defined a CMake target `libgdndk` for the library, so you can just do this:

```
target_link_libraries( hello-jni libgdndk app-glue )
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have changed the line to the one you suggested, but stil get the same error message.
Do I have to remove or edit anything else?

Comment: Did you clean your CMake cache and run CMake from *scratch* after making the change?

Comment: I actually don't know, i used "clear project" and "refresh linked c++ projects", followed by a "Make project" in Android Studio. Error message stays the same.

Comment: @slowcar To be sure, you can delete the CMake build folder (containing the CMakeCache.txt file).

Comment: i found the file and deleted it, does not change anything unfortunately. Maybe i'll try to find a project including an external library on Github. Or maybe i get a working sample from the Vendor some time...

Answer (score 0):

I finally got some help from the publisher of the lib, the (working) result looks quite similar to the code i tried, so maybe it was just the location of the library that was at fault.

```
add_library( gdndk SHARED IMPORTED )
include_directories( $ENV{userprofile}/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/blackberry/dynamics_sdk/sdk/libs/handheld/gd/inc)
set_target_properties(gdndk PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION $ENV{userprofile}/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/blackberry/dynamics_sdk/sdk/libs/handheld/gd/libs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libgdndk.so )
target_link_libraries( hello-jni gdndk )
```